# What movement is this book cover (Mischief by Ed McBain, Avon 1994) from?

Tags: book

When I first read this book as a kid, I was struck by the warped angles and stark design of its cover. In order to look up more examples of such art/design, it would be helpful to know what genre/movement such art is from. If anyone knows the artist who designed this cover, that would be great too.

[image: Mischief by Ed McBain]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

I do not have a definitive answer. But it reminds me of soviet constructivism: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=constructivist+ilustration

It reminds me also the metropolis poster: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=metropolis+original+poster

which probably had some futurism influence: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=futurism+art

It also has some elements common in the 80 aerograph style; Aerograph, gradients and masks), but darker.

Comment: Yes futurism looks like the best answer to me. For example, the pictures here [link](http://www.keithgarrow.com/modern-art-styles/futurism-art-movement.html) remind me of the illustration with it's curved angles. One big difference in the book cover is its monochrome colour scheme.